# Encoding problem with ASIHttpRequest response

Tags: iphone, xml, utf-8, asihttprequest, basecamp

Guys, I've tryied all and had not success.

**Creating:**

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]; 
request.delegate = self;
[request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/xml"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml; charset=UTF-8;"];
```

**Desplaying:**

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
        [self HideProgressing];

//      NSString *poweredBy = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"X-Powered-By"];
//      NSString *contentType = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];

        NSString *body = [request responseString];
        //NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@\n%@", body, request.responseStatusMessage);
```

Even "content-type" says it has UTF-8. But I see only stuff like "&#4857" instead cyrillic symbols.

Did somebody solve the same problem with encodings?

Data is from Basecamp API, if it helps. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a HTML Encode/decode problem. Note, URL encode/decode is different one.

Encode/decode table for cyrillic - http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm

The code approach:
http://code.google.com/p/statz/source/browse/trunk/NSString%2BHTML.h
http://code.google.com/p/statz/source/browse/trunk/NSString%2BHTML.m

Or this one: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/GTMNSString%2BHTML.m

I've not implemented yet, have another tasks now.

Good luck.